# Match Two columns in Xcel and Sum the other two

Tags: excel

I have the below data Set and in that I want to compare column A with column C and

- if the values of column A and C matches then I need to sum up the corresponding values in column B and column D in column E.
- if the values of column A and C doesn't match i.e. the values in Column A and C are unique then column E should return the value of column B and column D

**Raw Data Set**
[image: Raw Data Set]

**Expected**

[image: Expected]

Tried using vlookup but due to limited knowledge on excel, failed.

Comment: if(a1=c1,sum(b1,d1),0) would be one way, just drag down and it does each row. Now you changed the question, I will let you figure out the expansion needed.

Comment: Sorry Mike.. The expectation is somewhat like this based on the raw data set shared earlier in the original question:Expected 
Name                                Qty
Agrawal Brothers, Kothi         27
Deepak Traders, Maihar          8
Markfed Amarpatan         25
Markfed Amarpatan - CMS 27
Markfed Chorhata                192
Markfed Churhat                70
Markfed DevendNagar       115
Markfed DevrajNagar        258
Markfed Gunor               141
Markfed Gurh                       50

Comment: Please include markdown sample data, not screenshots.

Comment: Put all of your data into 2 columns and use a pivot table to consolidate your values.

Comment: @SolarMike : Any help please? I am in an urgent need of the solution.

Comment: @SolarMike -  Rest all is working fine except the text with "," as the formula is splitting the text after "," and considering it as a different text

Answer (score 0):

Move column C and D under column A and B.
Type in cell C1

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$34,A1,$B$1:$B$34)
```

copy down the end of the table.

Replace the 34 row value with the last row value in the table.

Apply the Advanced Filter in Data tab to column A data and select Unique records only.

Answer (score 0):

So, a simple solution:

```
SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7,B10)+SUMIFS($E$2:$E$7,$D$2:$D$7,B10)
```

[image]

Made some simple data as you did not provide anything to work with.
You should pay attention to errors due to leading or trailing spaces on the names.

Also, I used unique() to generate the list of names...

But another method to generate the list of names using all the names in both columns A & C is:

```
UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:A7,D2:D7),",")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike.. The values in column A and D won't necessarily have the same values and hence the uniqueness check you have proposed in column B10 wouldn't work. I dont know how to share the data through except sharing the screenshot :(

Comment: Well, you could consider having a helper column where you collect ALL the names then drive the unique() from that. Sometimes you need to help yourself. As for not being able to post data - you could enter a table of data instead of images - I was not going to type your stuff out.

Comment: "My email ID" you are dreaming. You need to read the FAQs provided explaining how this site works.

Comment: Hi Mike.. Thank you. Rest all is working fine except the text with "," as the formula is splitting the text after "," and considering it as a different text.

Comment: Mike - Can you please check my feedback on the solution you've shared ?

Comment: @SankitAgrawal not sure what you are doing wrong. I have two solutions that work based on data I put together. If your data has issues then I cannot tell what they are.

Comment: Lets assume the data as "Sankit Agrawal, India" and after putting the uniqueness formula , it is splitting the data in two different rows Sankit Agrawal in one row and India in second row.

Comment: @SankitAgrawal it should do, that is what it is designed to do. Why not put "Sankit Agrawal: India" or "Sankit Agrawal - India" instead? In fact just like the "Markfed Amarpatan - CMS" that you already have.../